# Is it possible to disable the watermark on GrabzIt api?

Tags: php, api

I'm am using **GrabzIt** api to grab a screenshot of a webpage, but the image have a watermark, is it possible to disable?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you have to purchase a premium package.

http://grabz.it/support/?id=517c0c4428fd9108dcd9c411

Comment: Lolx. As son as I saw the title, I knew that was going to be the answer!   (I can haz warez?)